# Webform address country field alter default error message (An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.) when is empty

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm working on a D8 project and I have a webform where I use webform_address type fields.

If the country (which is a mandatory field) in those fields is empty I'm getting the generic error "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.".

Is there any way to change it?

I tried to use the `hook_webform_element_alter` in order to add custom validation in my field but the country is a subfield of address field.

Any thought/idea/solution would be valuable!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Please isolate the problem, document how to replicate it, and create an issue in the Webform issue queue. (https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform?version=8.x)

Comment: Thank you @jrockowitz. I will do it now. For now, a workaround was to switch the country to dropdown.

Comment: Actually, after some extra testing today, I realised that after the latest module update, I had to change manually all they address fields (alter the country to textfield) and works fine. So I won't add it as a bug